# looping through bitmap into array

Tags: java, android, image-processing, bitmap

is it possible to loop through bitmap and set each color value to an array? at the moment only top row of array is getting written to dst bitmap. eg

.

```
Bitmap dst = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,input.getConfig() ); //output pic


          int origPixel = 0;
          int []arr = new int[input.getWidth()*input.getHeight()];
          int color = 0;

          for(int j=0;j<dst.getHeight();j++){
              for(int i=0;i<dst.getWidth();i++){

           origPixel= input.getPixel(i,j);

           color = ........do something special with that pixel transform it whatever



           if(  Math.pow(i - centerX, 2) + ( Math.pow(j - centerY, 2) )  <= 22500 ){

                arr[i]=color;

            }else{

                arr[i]=origPixel;
            }
  }

}

    Bitmap dst2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(arr,width,height,input.getConfig());
    return dst2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to update arr[k] where k initialize before first loop and increment in the second loop see the modified code a hunk of your code:

```
int k =0;
 for(int j=0;j<dst.getHeight();j++){
              for(int i=0;i<dst.getWidth();i++, k++){

           origPixel= input.getPixel(i,j);

           color = ........do something special with that pixel transform it whatever



           if(  Math.pow(i - centerX, 2) + ( Math.pow(j - centerY, 2) )  <= 22500 ){

                arr[k]=color;

            }else{

                arr[k]=origPixel;
            }
```

you are overriding values in array.

Comment: @asad rasheed hi, no that hasn't made a difference. i should increment the same as k shouldn't it?

Comment: no you aren't, you are writing pixels in array in second loop and override the values again from zero for every next row. try mine and let me know.

Comment: @asad rasheed yep i already have and the first row of pixels is showing in the dst bitmap. i've also logged out the i value along with the color value and the i value is getting reset on the outter loop

Comment: @turtleboy: you said **"i've also logged out the i value along with the color value and the i value is getting reset on the outter loop"** that is what I am trying to say. You are initializing i=0 every time in the inner loop that is the cause.

Comment: @asad rasheed ok i've initialzed i outside the loops. i'm getting the full bitmap now but the effect which is a fisheye effect within a circle in the center of the bitmap isn't present. The left 1/3 of the bitmap is on the right hand side and the pixels that make up the distortion seem to be spread across the top 1/3 of the bitmap. Normally i use dst.sepixel() to set the pixel but writing to an array seems to jumble up the order of pixels, any ideas why thanks

Comment: @turtleboy: that is why I suggest you to use a new variable like k.